# If content exists in database, provide form to update it - else provide form to add new row

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

It's all going wrong. I need to output a form onto my website that will do 1 of 2 things:

1. If the user already has content in the database, provide a form that posts to self to update the existing content.
2. If the user does not have content in the database, provide a form to let the user add information to the database.

The forms should submit to themselves to keep coding tidy. I'm getting into a right mess. I'll show what I have so far, but I'm getting in a muddle.

```
//look in db to see if content exists, if it does set variable
    $result = mysql_query(
            "SELECT * from tbl_profiles 
            WHERE user_id = $who
        ");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
             $profileText = $row['text'];
             }

// Check if user has content in db

        $result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM tbl_profiles WHERE user_id='$who'");

    if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){
        echo 
        '<form action="../edit/indexUpdate.php" method="post" name="edit">
                Comments:<br />
                <textarea name="updatedText" id="comments">' .
                $profileText .'
                </textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>'
        ;}
    else{
        $profileText = $row['text'];
        echo 
        "<form action='../edit/index.php' method='post' name='add'>
                Comments:<br />
                <textarea name='comments' id='comments'>" .
                $profileText 
                ."</textarea><br />
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
            </form>"
        ;}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much got the functionality there, just needs tidying up.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
//look in db to see if content exists, if it does set variable
$profileText="";
if($result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tbl_profiles WHERE user_id = $who")) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $profileText .= $row['text'];
         }
    ?>
    <form action="../edit/indexUpdate.php" method="post" name="edit">
            Comments:<br />
            <textarea name="updatedText" id="comments">
            <?php echo $profileText; ?>
            </textarea><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
     <form action='../edit/index.php' method='post' name='add'>
            Comments:<br />
            <textarea name='comments' id='comments'>
            <?php echo $profileText; ?> 
            </textarea><br />
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
     </form>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to add a record if new and update if not.  What you can do is use an id to represent the record or -1 if it's a new entry

Something along the lines of:

```
//Defaults
$recordid=-1;
$name='';
$comments='';
//look in db to see if content exists, if it does set variable
$result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * from tbl_profiles 
        WHERE user_id = $who
    ");
```

// Check if user has content in db
        $result = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM tbl_profiles WHERE user_id='$who'");

```
if(mysql_fetch_array($result) !== false){
   //Yes.  Get the id
    $recordid = $result->id;
   //Get the values
   $name= $result->name;
   $comments= $result->name;

}
```

---

```
<form action="../edit/index.php" method="post" name="formdata">
  <input type="hidden" name="recordid" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars($recordid) ?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars($name) ?>">
  <textarea name="comments" id="comments"><? echo htmlspecialchars($comments) ?></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

This way a new form will have a -1 but an existing will have an id.

As an additional point it is very important to sanitize your inputs for SQL and what you output in HTML to stop SQL Injections.  For your reference on this:

[SQL](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/3.html)

[Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

[Cross Site Scripting](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/)

Comment: This looks good, but it's getting flagged in dreamweaver with errors. Is this PHP?

Comment: It flags around the 'var' options

Comment: @user2527750 - Sorry about that... letting a little JavaScript blend into it when typing the code.  I've corrected it.